# How do I change a value in django on option click in HTML using Ajax-JavaScript?

Tags: python, django, ajax

I am trying to implement a function using Ajax-JavaScript in which when I click on Activate Option, the value in my Django database for this field changes to 'Active' and is displayed on the HTML page as active with Activate Message. If De-Activate is clicked, the text changes to De-Active along with it's value in the django database and show De-Activated message

HTML page:

```
<div class="col-sm-5">
<div class="panel panel-primary">
 <div class="panel-heading">
   <h3 class="panel-title">Job activation status</h3>
 </div>
   <div class="panel-body">
      <td> Campus Name </td>
      <td> hod_name </td>
      <td>
        <select name="status" class="form-control">
            <option value="1">Active</option>
            <option value="2">Disabled</option>
        </select>
    </td>

  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

**Model:**

```
class Campus(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        ('Active', 'Active'),
        ('Disabled', 'Disabled'),
    )
    campus_name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30)
    hod_name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=25)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS, default='Disabled', blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.campus_name
```

**View:**

```
def status_update(request, pk):
    campus_status = get_object_or_404(Campus, pk=pk)
    campus_status.status = 'Active' if campus_status.status == 'Disabled' else 'Disabled'
    campus_status.save(update_fields=['status'])
    messages.success(request, '{} Status: {} successfully'.format(campus_status.campus_name, campus_status.status))
    return redirect('/dashboard/create_campus/')
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this you would need to send a message to the views.py when the button is clicked where you would change the value.

I cannot show you how to do this immediately because not enough parts of your code is shown, could you please add your views.py section.

Comment: def status_update(request, pk):
    campus_status = get_object_or_404(Campus, pk=pk)
    campus_status.status = 'Active' if campus_status.status == 'Disabled' else 'Disabled'
    campus_status.save(update_fields=['status'])
    messages.success(request, '{} Status: {} successfully'.format(campus_status.campus_name, campus_status.status))
    return redirect('/dashboard/create_campus/')

Comment: I am new to django I do not how to do define the view for it?

Comment: I then recommend you read through the django documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: This will teach you how to do what you want to do and more as it seems you are a beginner in django but good at js

Comment: I have made a few website using django, but did not use Ajax, now I want to use Ajax, I applied this function that refresh all the page, now I want not to refresh the whole page to be again and again when I change the status.

Comment: I understand what you are doing now and I would not recommend trying to use js or ajax in your html code. I would recommend using django instead of js for the normal html forms and django for the backend also

Answer (score 0):

```
def status_update(request, pk):
    campus_status = get_object_or_404(Campus, pk=pk)
    campus_status.status = 'Active' if campus_status.status == 'De-Activated' else 'Disabled'
    campus_status.save(update_fields=['status'])
    messages.success(request, '{} Status: {} successfully'.format(campus_status.campus_name, campus_status.status))
    return redirect('/dashboard/create_campus/')
```